# How to get data from web page without scrolling using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

How to get all data from the webpage without using scroll or page up and down.

[image]

```
    int n = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@type=\"text\"]")));
            List<WebElement> FV = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@type=\"text\"]"));
            WebElement aa = FV.get(i);
            String cc = aa.getAttribute("value");
            System.out.println(cc);
```

After I run this code it displays blank.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `scroll or page up and down`? What is your _usecase_?

Comment: What do you wants to target by scrolling ?

Comment: I want to read all data on different screens.  that screens may have a different size.so I don't want to use the scroll or any keys